# Where can I find the list of questions I (un-)protected?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, protected-questions

It looks like everything I did is listed in my own profile, at least for my own perusal.

Still, I failed to find any notice of the questions I protected / unprotected.

Is it just that I didn't look in the right place, or is that actually missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The questions that you have protected or unprotected isn't listed in a user profile, but you can use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get it.

I wrote a quick query to [get the list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394726/my-unprotected-questions).  Feel free to create a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking it to be added...somewhere...at some point.

Comment: Added the feature-request, though on MSE: [Please add the list of questions (un-)protected to the profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269628/please-add-the-list-of-questions-un-protected-to-the-profile-page)